# How to display empty ng2-pdfjs-viewer when no file provided

Tags: angular, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

I'm using ng2-pdfjs-viewer to display pdfs in my angular page:

```
<ng2-pdfjs-viewer [pdfSrc]="src">
</ng2-pdfjs-viewer>
```

**Behavior** : i get src from server, when it's not empty or null it's working correctly, but when null or emty ng2-pdfjs-viewer crashes.

**Expeced** : display an empty  ng2-pdfjs-viewer when src is null or empty (or a loading indicator inside)

Comment: Does browser console say anything? any error there?

Answer (score 3):

Put *ngIf with this component.
It will solve null or empty src case.

```
    <ng2-pdfjs-viewer *ngIf="src" [pdfSrc]="src"> 
</ng2-pdfjs-viewer>
```